# How to query the database to include only sought element and the path to it for API Json?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, entity-framework, .net-core

I need to construct a function for the net-core/ef-core API that shows an element in a database with the data of each object in the path leading to it.

So, basically there is such structure:
Many Cities, each has a list of:
Multiple Areas in a City, each has a list of:
Multiple Shops in Area, each offer has a list of:
Multiple Offer Entries in Shop, each has a single variable with the:
Product connected to it by a foreign key. A shop can have only one Offer entry for each Product (unique offers). All DbSets are visible below in the first block of code (Includes).

I have 2 variables:
`string cityName` and `string productName`.

So I made such query:

```
IQueryable<City> cityNameQuery = _context.Cities
   .Include(x => x.Areas)
       .ThenInclude(x => x.Shops)
           .ThenInclude(x => x.ShopOfferEntries)
              .ThenInclude(x => x.ProductData).Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.Name, "%" + cityName + "%")).AsQueryable();
```

Then made such filtering:

```
cityNameQuery = cityNameQuery.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(cityName))
   .Where(l => l.Areas.Where(x => x.Shops
   .Where(y => y.ShopOfferEntries
   .Where(z => z.ProductData.Name.Contains(productName)).Any()).Any()).Any());
```

Then gather it to a list and return:

```
if (pricesByCity == null || pricesByCity.Count() == 0)
   {
      return Json("Product not available in this city.");
   }       
pricesByCity = cityNameQuery.ToList();
return Json(pricesByCity);
```

The result either shows "Product not available in this city" or whole City with all areas, all shops and all their offers, including data of other products in their offers. But all that data isn't needed.

What Json API should print would be:

1. City that has the Area with product
2. That Area should show only a Shop that has the Product
3. That Shop should show only the offer with the Product
4. That Offer should show only the data of the Product
5. The Product data itself.

So we probably need to strip away other elements in the lists, as each City has many Areas, Areas have Many Shops etc. and we should show only those that lead to the sought product.

Thought I could filter out the json result client-side, but that's not going to be a wise solution.
Is there any fast, integrated way to show only the path to an item in a database?
How can we change the above code to do that most efficiently? Or maybe I should restructure the database to get such a result?